# delete button is only deleting last item in array of objects instead of the specified object in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, redux-toolkit

need help deleting an object in an array in redux toolkit
Hi, the trouble im facing is that I have a delete button on the Ui of my application. This is my code, and whenever I click the delete button, it only deletes the last item in the array and not the correct item. The index is being sent through the payload. Thanks for your help in advance

```
const initialState: ExperienceState = {
  form: [
 {
      companyName: "",
      position: "",
      responsibilities: "",
      startDate: "",
      endDate: "",
 },
 ],
};


    deleteForm: (state, action): any => {
      state.form = state.form.filter((__, index) => index !== action.payload);
    },
```

i tried using the splice method to delete the single object but that also didnt work.

I think it might be a problem with the key prop somehow.

```
  <div>
        {experiences.form.map((data, index) => {
          return <ExperienceForm key={index} formkey={index} data={data} />;
        })}
      </div>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but FYI, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will pass the `index` as a second argument so you don't have to do an `indexOf` at each step (which btw is making your `filter` call O(N^2) instead of O(N) like normal). E.g. do `.filter((element, index) => index !== action.payload)`

Comment: ok just changed that, but still not sure why only the last item of array is being deleted

Comment: @as-0234 I would be willing to bet it's not. Try console.logging your entire `form` state after a delete. I think your problem is you're rendering an array but you're setting the `key` on the JSX element to be the index of the array, rather than an actual identifier of some sort

Comment: Either that, or the `index` you're passing into `deleteForm` as the payload is always the last index.

Comment: @TKoL yea i tried logging the form array. Its weird, when all objects should be deleted, there is still one object in the array but not this is not being shown on the UI. 

The process I used was to map through the form array and return a component sending in the index. This index was meant to be the same index as the object in the array. should I instead use something like UUID?

Comment: `should I instead use something like UUID` yes

Comment: so Ive made a key in the object for uuid and this is assigned when a form is created. 
This is the updated deleteForm function:

`   deleteForm: (state, action): any => {
      state.form = state.form.filter(
        (data, index) => data.uuid !== action.payload
      );
    },

for some reason its still doing the same thing, only deleting the last item

Comment: i thought i fixed it but still doesnt work, so on the actual array it deleted the correct item, its just on the dom it removes the last item, not sure why this is? @TKoL